# Cucumber Spring DI two Step classes loading Spring context

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, cucumber-java

I'm using cucumber-spring to create my integration tests and use DI provided by Spring.
The way it's done: there is a separate project that defines all the necessary cucumber dependencies:

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
           <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
           <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
           <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
           <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
           <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
           <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
       </dependency>
```

The project also has a base test class annotated with SpringBootTest (that allows to load application context):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {SomeBeans.class}
)
public class BaseTestStateSteps {
```

I'm adding this project as a dependency in the pom of my project:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.externalproject</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-test-cucumber</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I have my runner class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "junit:target/cucumber/cucumber.xml", "json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json",
                "html:target/cucumber/html/"},
        tags = {"@Smoke"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"com.externalproject.steps","com.mycompany.steps"}
)
public class RunTestIT {
}
```

And I also have my Step class:

```
public class MyTestSteps {

    @Autowired
    ClassToAutowire classToAutowire;

    @Given("^I can do something$")
    public void generateRandomPhoneNumber() {
        classToAutowirer.doSomething();
    }
```

So the issue I'm running:
- if I don't have my RunTestIT annotated with SpringBootTest or with ContextConfiguration - ClassToAutowire is null (it's not autowired);
- if I addone of those annotations I'm running into error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Glue class class com.externalproject.steps.BaseTestStateSteps and class com.mycompany.steps.MyTestSteps both attempt to configure the spring context. Please ensure only one glue class configures the spring context
```

I need the functionality of Steps from external project (so I don't have to copy/paste from there and get the latest feature updates), but I also need dependencies from my spring context to be autowired.

I read the article https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2018/03/31/cucumber-tests-spring-boot-dependency-injection/
But it only deals with multiple step definitions inside the same project.

Do you have any ideas how I can solve the issue?

Comment: If you can create an MCVE you might want to report this as a bug.